# how to compute covariance in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, covariance

I have a problem that I don't know how to compute the covariance of two tensor. I have tried the `contrib.metrics.streaming_covariance`. But is always returns `0`. There must be some errors.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the definition of the covariance of two random variables `X` and `Y` with the expected values `x0` and `y0`:

`cov_xx = 1 / (N-1) * Sum_i ((x_i - x0)^2)`

`cov_yy = 1 / (N-1) * Sum_i ((y_i - y0)^2)`

`cov_xy = 1 / (N-1) * Sum_i ((x_i - x0) * (y_i - y0))`

The crucial point is to estimate `x0` and `y0` here, since you normally do not know the probability distribution. In many cases, the mean of the `x_i` or `y_i` is estimated to be `x_0` or `y_0`, respectively, i.e. the distribution is estimated to be uniform.

Then you can compute the elements of the covariance matrix as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 24, 15], dtype=tf.float64)
y = tf.constant([8, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float64)

cov_xx = 1 / (tf.shape(x)[0] - 1) * tf.reduce_sum((x - tf.reduce_mean(x))**2)
cov_yy = 1 / (tf.shape(x)[0] - 1) * tf.reduce_sum((y - tf.reduce_mean(y))**2)
cov_xy = 1 / (tf.shape(x)[0] - 1) * tf.reduce_sum((x - tf.reduce_mean(x)) * (y - tf.reduce_mean(y)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([cov_xx, cov_yy, cov_xy])
    print(cov_xx.eval(), cov_yy.eval(), cov_xy.eval())
```

Of course, if you need the covariance in a matrix form, you can modify the last part as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([cov_xx, cov_yy, cov_xy])
    print(cov_xx.eval(), cov_yy.eval(), cov_xy.eval())
    cov = tf.constant([[cov_xx.eval(), cov_xy.eval()], [cov_xy.eval(),
        cov_yy.eval()]])
    print(cov.eval())
```

To verify the elements of the TensorFlow way, you can check with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,4,2,5,6, 24, 15], dtype=float)
y = np.array([8,5,4,6,2,1,1], dtype=float)

pc = np.cov(x,y)
print(pc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [tensorflow probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/covariance) for easy calculation of correlation or covariance.

```
x = tf.random_normal(shape=(100, 2, 3))
y = tf.random_normal(shape=(100, 2, 3))

# cov[i, j] is the sample covariance between x[:, i, j] and y[:, i, j].
cov = tfp.stats.covariance(x, y, sample_axis=0, event_axis=None)

# cov_matrix[i, m, n] is the sample covariance of x[:, i, m] and y[:, i, n]
cov_matrix = tfp.stats.covariance(x, y, sample_axis=0, event_axis=-1)
```