# how to get covariance matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

How could I get covariance matrix in tensorflow? Like `numpy.cov()` in `numpy`.

For example, I want to get covariance matrix of tensor `A`, now I have to use numpy instead

```
    A = sess.run(model.A, feed)
    cov = np.cov(np.transpose(A))
```

Is there anyway to get `cov` by tensorflow instead of numpy?

It is differnet from the problem [how to compute covariance in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874928/how-to-compute-covariance-in-tensorflow), where their problem is to compute covariance for two vector, while mine is to compute covariance matrix of a matrix(a 2D tensor) effectively using tensorflow API

Comment: You could check the [streaming_covariance](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_covariance) fn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compute covariance in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874928/how-to-compute-covariance-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is months late but anyway posting for completeness.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_cov(x):
    mean_x = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
    mx = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(mean_x), mean_x)
    vx = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), x)/tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.float32)
    cov_xx = vx - mx
    return cov_xx

data = np.array([[1., 4, 2], [5, 6, 24], [15, 1, 5], [7,3,8], [9,4,7]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_cov(tf.constant(data, dtype=tf.float32))))

    
## validating with numpy solution
pc = np.cov(data.T, bias=True)
print(pc)
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering from 2019. Tensorflow probability now supports effortless correlation and covariance.

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/covariance

```
x = tf.random_normal(shape=(100, 2, 3))
y = tf.random_normal(shape=(100, 2, 3))

# cov[i, j] is the sample covariance between x[:, i, j] and y[:, i, j].
cov = tfp.stats.covariance(x, y, sample_axis=0, event_axis=None)

# cov_matrix[i, m, n] is the sample covariance of x[:, i, m] and y[:, i, n]
cov_matrix = tfp.stats.covariance(x, y, sample_axis=0, event_axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to `np.cov(data)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1., 4, 2], [5, 6, 24], [15, 1, 5], [7,3,8], [9,4,7]])

def tf_conv(x):
    x = x - tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1), 1)
    fact = tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[1] - 1, tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(x, tf.conj(tf.transpose(x))) / fact

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_cov(tf.constant(data, dtype=tf.float32))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Souradeep Nanda, if you experiment with it you'll find that tfp.stats.covariance is only have the value (elementwise) for np.cov(..., rowvar=False), so you will have to multiply by 2 after the calculation. (This applies for v0.11.1, tested on 2x2 matrix).

For 3x3 matrix, the values are NOT EQUIVALENT so perhaps you might want to stay using np.cov. This applies too if you're not using rowvar=False for np.cov() version. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tfp` aka [tensorflow-probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/install) to computer cov matrix:

```
import tensorflow-probability as tfp

x=tf.random.normal(shape=(3,3))
cov = tfp.stats.covariance(x)
## which are same as:
np_cov = np.cov(tf.transpose(x_zero),bias=True)
```

Comment: A dash in a Python import is not valid syntax. Should be `import tensorflow_probability as tfp`.